# css responsive: mobile version

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I'm new in CSS and I'm creating a responsive design with media queries.
When I change the size of the browser to 480px or less (@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)) the design work fine but when I open it on mobile or use the toggle device toolbar on chrome, it goes too small and I didn't get the same design as on desktop with small window

Is there something missing (another media query or something else) to make the design on mobile the same as on small window in desktop.

Thank you in advance

Comment: For the desktop, it is possible that it is an issue with `Toggle device toolbar`. Just refresh the page if it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try adding this to your HTML?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

My guess is the zoom is your problem. Either that, or the actual resolution of your phone might be higher than 480px in width.

The line of code I pasted is part of [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), which is *the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.* (quote from their website. I don't disagree though).

I suggest taking a look at bootstrap as it's made with media queries and is really thought for responsive websites.